# Swift. UISegmentedControl with two different lines

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to make a UISegmentedControl with two lines and a different fonts and sizes.

I managed to make it so that there were two lines, but I don’t know how to make different sizes and fonts.

```
for segment in segmentedControl.subviews{
    for label in segment.subviews{
        if let labels = label as? UILabel{
            labels.numberOfLines = 2


        }
    }
}
segmentedControl.setTitle("Hiragana \n ひらがな", forSegmentAt: 0)
segmentedControl.setTitle("Katakana \n カタカナ", forSegmentAt: 1)
```

Now I have something like this:

[image]

And want like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`UISegmentedControl` does not provide support for attributed titles like `UILabel` so there is no support for titles with two different fonts.

One solution would be to create a `UIImage` from an `NSAttributedString` and then use the images with your segmented control.

Another option would be to create your own (or find a 3rd party) custom control that works with attributed titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve by the default functionality provided by apple

but you can loop through subview as you doing for the number of lines thing

and add

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hiragana",
                                               attributes: [ 
NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) ])

    attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "ひらがな",
                                                attributes: 
[NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40) ]))
```

then add this to the label

```
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: This is risky since a future iOS update might change the implementation of the segmented control. There is also the problem of the order of the labels and trying to set the correct title to the correct label. This is why I didn't mention this solution in my answer. It's always a bad plan to dig into the private subview structure of a control.